# Replace archived app in iTunes Connect

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

I archived the app I made, but then later made some changes. I'd like to replace the archived app with this new version. When I go to archive it, it gives me an error that says version 1 already exists. How do I get rid of the old one and replace it with the new one? I have not submitted anything for reviews yet. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the error that you see but try to change the build number:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is related to build number error. Keep the version number same and change the build number by increasing one. And Now try to upload a new archive and itunes will accept this.

For example, You have uploaded last archive with version 1.0 and build number 1.0. Now, if you want to upload a new archive for the same version i.e. 1.0, then simply change the build number 1.1 and that's it.

Comment: If it is worked for you then please up vote and accept this answer. It'll be helpful to other developers also.

Comment: It doesn't let me because I'm a newbie :(